# how to kill an app started by `quickly run`

Tags: quickly, pygtk

I am building an app and it hangs on some thread . how can i kill that app ?

tried ctrl+c but it didn't work (the icon stays in the notification area)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to kill it via the process list:

[image: Process List]

Or - if you want to be more nerdy - kill it via the console, using `$>top`

Comment: i just didnt know it's name ... it was python :s

Comment: Maybe you can identify it using `pstree`. I suggest looking through the leaves.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of your process, `grep` against `ps` to get the PID (process ID).  Example: If I wanted to stop shotwell, I would do this (from a terminal session):

```
$ ps -ef | grep shotwell
xaap001   1779  1139  8 08:08 ?        00:00:01 shotwell
xaap001   1792  1703  0 08:08 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto shotwell
```

The first process listed is the one I want (in this example), and the first number listed is the PID.  You can also see that the command I just ran is listed in there, too.

Now that I have my PID (1779), I can stop the process with this command:

```
$ kill -9 1779
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you enter

```
Cntl-z
```

That will suspend the process and tell you its job number.

then:

```
kill -9 %1
```

if its job number is 1. After you press enter the first time it will mention that [1] is stopped. The next time you press enter it will tell you it is killed or terminated.

Comment: +1: this is exactly what I do. You can omit the `-9` code though.